# Facebook data breach issue

Tags: facebook

I deactivated my Facebook account back in June (7 months ago), but something weird happened about 48 hours go. Yesterday, I got informed that someone was sharing my info on a Facebook group with some of my old pics photoshopped (the post was dated Sunday morning). The things is puzzling me is that my Facebook has not being active for months and all my pictures were only shared with restricted audience of close family.
I tried to reach out to Facebook to get an explanation but I hit a brick wall.
Technically when an account is deactivated nobody should be able to get content, the only explanation is Facebook per se has been breached.
Thoughts?